# Using the difference quotient to find f prime for: $f(x)=\sqrt{3x}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I am trying to find the derivative for: f(x)=sqrt(3x) 
from using the difference quotient,

f'(x) = lim h-> 0: (f(x+h) - f(x))/h

and 
find f'(12).

How do I do this using the difference quotient? If I use derivative rules (which I am not allowed to use in class at this time), I find that f'(12) = 1/4.

When I use the difference quotient I multiply by the conjugate of the numerator so the conjugate of: *sqrt(3x+h) - sqrt(3x)* ,being *sqrt(3x+h) + sqrt(3x)* and the denominator by the same conjugate but when I solve I still get 1/12 and not 1/4.

Could anyone show me how to correctly use the difference quotient to solve f'(12) for f(x)=sqrt(3x)?

Thanks

Comment: You mention your function is $f(x) = 3\sqrt{x}$ but are using $\sqrt{3x}$ in your difference quotient. These aren't the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}=\frac{\sqrt{3x+3h}-\sqrt{3x}}{h}\frac{\sqrt{3x+3h}+\sqrt{3x}}{\sqrt{3x+3h}+\sqrt{3x}}=\frac{3h}{h(\sqrt{3x+3h}+\sqrt{3x})}$$
when $h\rightarrow0$
$$f'(x)=\frac{3}{2\sqrt{3x}}=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2\sqrt{x}}$$
so
$$f'(12)=\frac{1}{4}$$

Comment: Thanks, I was getting stuck because I did 3x+h and not 3x+3h, which resulted in me multiplying by the wrong conjugate.